# Gereralise the query for all user_id

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, greatest-n-per-group

I have a mysql query

```
select sum(duration),app_name,app_id,user_id 
from timesheet 
where user_id=164 
group by app_id 
order by sum(duration) desc 
limit 5;
```

The result is

```
sum(duration), app_name,       app_id,  user_id
'626919371',   'Idle.exe',     '0',     '164'
'38220511',    'LockApp.exe',  '2204',  '164'
'36675000',    '',             '1',     '164'
'27713000',    'LockApp.exe',  '8148',  '164'
'16698661',    'chrome.exe',   '8548',  '164'
```

However I want the top 5 app for every user_id instead of just 164. Can you pelase guide me as to how this can be achieved in a single query. Or do I need to fire it for every individual user

Comment: Specify your MySQL version.

Comment: my MYSQL version is 5.7.16

Comment: I'd recommend to get the data for all apps in subquery, then enumerate records over  the user and return only those where number is 5 or less (emulate ROW_NUMBER) using user-defined variables.

Comment: Upgrade to version 8 and use Window (or Analytic) functions! **The** way to go!

Comment: OK, @Vérace -- Let's see the windowing code.

Comment: Pre 8.0 code:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max

Comment: @RickJames - if the OP indicates that he [wishes to | can] upgrade, then gladly. It's a bit moot though if that's not going to happen and the supplied answer will do the job without an upgrade. Of course, there are all sorts of other good reasons to upgrade to 8 apart from Window functions (CTEs, [generated | calculated | computed] fields and (finally, hallelujah, praise the Lord, 30 years after other RDBMSs have them), CHECK constraints! p.s. like your site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
select sum_duration, 
       app_name, 
       app_id, 
       user_id
from ( select get_data.*,
              if( @user_id = get_data.user_id, 
                  @rownum := @rownum + 1, 
                  @rownum := 1 + least(0, @user_id := get_data.user_id)) row_number
       from ( select sum(duration) sum_duration, 
                     app_name, 
                     app_id, 
                     user_id 
              from timesheet 
              group by app_id ) get_data, 
            ( select @rownum := 1, @user_id := 0 ) init_vars
       order by user_id, sum_duration DESC
     ) subquery
where row_number <= 5
```